# Pute the callback-console.log from epic-games-api in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I want to put the epic games output in the express js get. I have 0 experience with js, so please no hate if it doesn't make sense. XD

```
const EpicGamesAPI = require('epicgames-status');
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

EpicGamesAPI().then(callback => {
    const epicgames = console.log(callback);
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(epicgames)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: my cosole.log = {
  
EpicGames: 'Operational',
  EpicGamesStore: 'Operational',
  Fortnite: {
    Status: 'Operational',
    Website: 'Operational',
    GameServices: 'Operational',
    Login: 'Operational',
    Parties: 'Operational',
    Voice: 'Operational',
    HousepartyVoice: 'Operational',
    Matchmaking: 'Operational',
    Stats: 'Operational',
    ItemShop: 'Operational',
    FortniteCrew: 'Operational'
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`epicgames` in `res.send(epicgames)` is not in the same scope as `const epicgames = console.log(callback);`. You can place the EpicGamesAPI callback in the get callback:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    EpicGamesAPI().then(callback => {
        const epicgames = console.log(callback);
        res.send(epicgames);
    })
})
```

When you make the get request, the EpicGamesAPI will be called. You might want to send `callback` to res.send, rather than a console.log.

Comment: ok, but i got in blank screen, if i make in request

Comment: @Lucas So from your frontend application, you will want to parse the data you receive. It looks like you get { EpicGames: 'Operational', EpicGamesStore: 'Operational',...} in the console.log you provided. So on your frontend, you can console.log(data), where data is the data received from your API request. If you then look in your console.log on the frontend, you will see your data. If you want the data displayed on your screen, you then need to parse it to get each value in the object.

Comment: my idea was to pack the output in a json rest api, and use that data on a php website